# Displaying multiple tables from model in single view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables `TxtComment` and `Login`.

I am displaying image urls from `Login` table and comments from `TxtComment` table where username in `TxtComment` equals username in `Login`.

I am using Db First approach using entityframework.

How can I concatenate these columns from different tables to one common view? I used ViewBag. I got a result.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Item(int id)
{  
    FoodContext db = new FoodContext();

    ViewBag.FoodItems = db.FoodItems.Where(row => row.itemid == id);

    ViewBag.TxtComments = (from user in db.TxtComments
                           from ff in db.Logins
                           where ff.username == user.username
                           select new { imgurl = ff.imgurl, txtcmt = user.txtcmt });

    return View();

}
```

**View**

```
@for(var item in ViewBag.TxtComments)
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

The result is `{imgurl=http:/sdfsdf,txtcmt=sfsdfsdf}`

I need each item seperate. How can I? I tried with `@item.imgurl`, it says error. Is view bag is better? If not, please help me this need with strongly type view.

Comment: Don't use `ViewBag`, create a `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own `ViewModel` instead of putting the model inside the `ViewBag`.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ImageComment> ImageComments { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ImageComments = new List<ImageComment>();
    }
}

public class ImageComment
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ViewResult Item(int id)
{
    FoodContext db = new FoodContext();

    List<ImageComment> comments = (from user in db.TxtComments
                                   from ff in db.Logins
                                   where ff.username == user.username
                                   select new ImageComment
                                   { 
                                       ImageUrl = ff.imgurl, 
                                       Comment = user.txtcmt 
                                   }).ToList();

    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel{ ImageComments = comments };     
    return View("MyView", vm);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Comments";
}

@foreach(ImageComment comment in Model.ImageComments)
{
    <p>@comment.Comment</p>
    <img src="@comment.ImageUrl" alt="img" />
}
```

Comment: can you please post view(presentation) also

Comment: Updated my answer to include view.

Comment: @for(var comment in Model.ImageComments) shows implicitly typed local variables must be initialized

Comment: i made a new model class just copy pasted your code

Comment: @user3274324, there was a typo in `foreach` (was `for`).